# A new column based on five-character strings in R

Tags: r, dplyr

```
A <- c("", "dog", "", "", "")

B <- c("cat", "", "", "", "")

C <- c("", "", "", "", "zebra")

D <- c("", "", "bird", "", "")

E <- c("", "", "", "mouse", "")

df <- data.frame(A, B, C, D, E)
```

I want to create column F containing the animal names from each row, such that column F includes dog in the first row, cat in the second row, zebra in the third row, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should be what you're looking for

```
df$F <- apply(df,1, function(x) x[which.max(nchar(x))])
```

***EDIT**

To use certain columns you would do something similar to the following

```
df$F <- apply(df[ ,5:12],1, function(x) x[which.max(nchar(x))])
```

Comment: Hi @stefan_aus_hannover, in my real data frame I need to apply this function across columns 5:12. Any help with that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply index out the blank values, avoiding having to implicitly loop with `apply`:

```
df[df != ""] # Thanks @Ludwig!
# [1] "dog"   "cat"   "zebra" "bird"  "mouse"
```

So

```
df$F <- df[df != ""]

#     A   B     C    D     E     F
# 1     cat                    dog
# 2 dog                        cat
# 3               bird       zebra
# 4                    mouse  bird
# 5         zebra            mouse
```

Comment: Ah, beautiful simplicity.

Comment: Thanks @Ludwig! _Even simpler!_  I have improved the answer based on your comment

Answer (score 3):

If you want dog in the first row, cat in the second row, zebra in the third row..

```
df$F <- apply(df, 2, paste, collapse = "")
```

In case you want cat first, then dog, then bird..

```
df$F <- apply(df, 1, paste, collapse = "")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `paste` with `do.call`

```
df$F <- do.call(paste, c(df, sep = ""))
```

and you will obtain

```
> df
    A   B     C    D     E     F
1     cat                    cat
2 dog                        dog
3               bird        bird
4                    mouse mouse
5         zebra            zebra
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(A, B, C, D, E) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(A, B, C, D, E), ~ ifelse(.=='',NA,.)), f=coalesce(A, B, C, D, E))


     A    B     C    D     E     f
1 <NA>  cat  <NA> <NA>  <NA>   cat
2  dog <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>   dog
3 <NA> <NA>  <NA> bird  <NA>  bird
4 <NA> <NA>  <NA> <NA> mouse mouse
5 <NA> <NA> zebra <NA>  <NA> zebra
```

Comment: While this is the most robust solution to the problem in general, it fails at one point: The order of the names is from top to bottom instead of left to right.

Comment: @jkatam this doesn’t seem to answer the question, you may want to edit your answer to ensure it matches the OP’s desired output.